# How to deal with Id in DTO in rest API

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui

Let's consider a simple `UserDTO`

```
public record UserDTO(string Id, string Username);
```

It means that in Swagger, for the `POST` request, both Id and Username will be asked, so that Id won't be used. Maybe it's confusing for the client.

On the other hand for `GET` requests, it could be useful.

What is the proper way to avoid this confusion?

-use only a `Username` string for the `POST` parameter (Here OK but messy with 10 properties)

-2 different DTO for `POST` and `GET` (lot of redundancy)

-other option?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create separate DTO for distinct endpoints.

- POST /users accepts `CreateUserDto(..relevant properties for creation..)
- GET /users - return List. Where UserDto(string Id, ...other properties)
  and so on.

Don't be afraid of creating more types, even if there is some duplication between them. You can always derive common abstractions later.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. I'm new to this concept and spent too much time to find an answer that clears this up.

Answer (score 2):

A DTO is by definition about transferring data, so it should be completely dependent on the data that you want to transfer. In most cases, using the same DTO for unrelated endpoints with different purposes makes no sense. Even if some of the fields are the same in different endpoints, specific DTO's would be recommended, don't consider this *code duplication*.

For example, in a basic `GET` endpoint where you want to retrieve an item by its ID, only the ID is needed, so you can even skip using a DTO, and make your endpoint accept a single `id` parameter.
For more complex `GET` endpoints, allowing you to filter, order, paginate, etc. a DTO containing all those criteria might be useful.

On the `POST` side, if you are generating your ID's in the server (as you probably should if you are storing the items in some database), you don't need that field posted from the client. It would be confussing for the client to have such a field in your DTO, since you would be ignoring it!